# Is this an example of indirect speech?

Tags: past-tense, indirect-speech, backshifting, mood

I wrote:

> School starts in August next year? I thought it started in September.

I proposed that this is one good example of how grammar can confuse people because a preterite *(started)* is used to talk about the future.

She replied that it's an example of tense shift in indirect speech.

Is it?

I didn't think so originally. But I can see how *I thought* x can be conceptualized as a reporting of one's own (inner) speech.

Does the utterance contain indirect speech? Yes, no, sometimes/maybe?

Comment: No, Jim. Not at all; never, ever.

However correct your analysis of the stated example in its own right, that will never have anything to do with direct or indirect speech.

Is that much clear?

Comment: More… Direct speech would suggest “School starts in August next year? I thought it started in September…”. That has nothing to do with grammar, semantics or syntax; it’s simply what was actually said.

The same in indirect speech would be, eg, “someone said that school started in August next year? I thought it started in September…”.

Still nothing to do with grammar, semantics or syntax; it’s simply what was loosely reported as having been said.

None of that is any example of how grammar can confuse people, however much you yourself were confused.